# Problem with Automata simple conditional statements in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, automata

I am trying to build an automata, I've dried run several times and there seems no problem in the code but still I am not getting the desired result i.e "CurrentState" which should be X3

Input I am giving is as follow

```
string[] input = new string[4] { "a", "a", "b", "z" };
```

I will simplify the transitions.However, table is given below
I am giving A, A, B which should lead to X3
X1 A X1----------X1 A X1------------X1 B X3------ (its stuck at X1) I've dried run the code as well, It should fall in scope with x3
  Transition Table is as follow

```
states2    token actions    output
x1               a            x1
x1               b            x3
x2               a            x2
x2               b            x1
x3               a            x3
x3               b            x4
x4               a            x2
x4               b            x3
```

Here is the code

```
 for (k = 0; k < input.Length; k++) //It is 4
        {
            if (input[k] == "z")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(currentState);
                break;
                //  Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                for (j = 0; j < tokenActions.Length; j++) //its 8 and same as states and output
                {

                    if (currentState == states2[j] && input[k] == tokenActions[j])
                    {
                        currentState = output[j];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE: I am noticing that the state is changing only ONCE which is for the first token and stays the same afterwards. (my observation, it maybe wrong)

Comment: Your program has a bug that is obvious to me, but not obvious to you. **It will become obvious to you when you run the code in a debugger**, so learn how to use a debugger.  What you want to do is put a breakpoint on where the state changes, and then **before you run the program** make a prediction of what the state changes should be.  Then run the program and see if the state changes are as you predicted. They will not be. Then figure out why!

Comment: It will help us help you if you give a **complete program that we can run**. Right now your program is just in fragments and you have not shown the whole thing. You have (probably) shown the part with the bug, which is good, but if the bug were in, say, your state transition table, you've only shown us the table and not the code.  **Show all the relevant code in your question**.

Comment: I've been debugging and using breakpoints, still can't come to find out. As you figured out(the bug) maybe you will be kind enough to mention ?

Comment: That is the code, other part is just the reading data from files. States2 has states, tokenActions has tokens and output has the result State. They are all of string arrays.. i will still edit and add to code

Comment: Like I said, put the breakpoint *where `currentState` changes*, then *make a prediction of what the changes should be before you run the program*. Then run the program and see if your prediction was right. It will not be right; where it is wrong is where the bug is.  Hint:  **how many times per character input should the state change**?

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for mentioning, there wasn't any error in code, the filereader was reading an extra space (very tiny one to notice)
However, thank you for taking time out to help :)

Comment: **There is still an error in the code**.  You are getting the answer x3, but you are getting it *by accident*, not because the code is correct.

Comment: @EricLippert I've changed the tokens (input) and the answer is as per the expectations, Quiet strange...
Please point out the error if you notice any?
*I chose the tokens as b,b,a  and the answer is x2 which is correct.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the process by which you reached the answer is wrong. You are getting the right answer entirely by accident; for some test cases you will get the wrong answer.  I've posted an instrumented version of your code that illustrates the bug much more clearly; see if you can find it.

Comment: Well that wasted a lot of my time this morning.

Answer (score 3):

You said that there was an error in your file reader, but **there is still an error in your code**.

Here, I've instrumented your code so that its action is more clear.  Before you run this program, **make a prediction of what its output should be**. Then run the program. Was the output correct?

```
public static void Main()
{
    string currentState = "x1";
    string[] input = {"a", "a", "b", "z"};
    string[] states2 = {"x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4"};
    string[] tokenActions = {"a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b" };
    string[] output = {"x1", "x3", "x2", "x1", "x3", "x4", "x2", "x3"};

    for (int k = 0; k < input.Length; k++) //It is 4
    {
        if (input[k] == "z")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("final state is {0}", currentState);
            break;
            //  Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("new input {0}", input[k]);
            for (int j = 0; j < tokenActions.Length; j++) //its 8 and same as states and output
            {
                if (currentState == states2[j] && input[k] == tokenActions[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("input is {0} current state is {1} new state is {2}", input[k], currentState, output[j]);
                    currentState = output[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now do you see your error?

Ask yourself: **how could I have prevented this error when I originally wrote the code**?  What ideas do you have for ways you could have written the code more clearly, so that you could not write this bug?